# MongoTemplate find by date conversion

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I am trying to convert the following query:

```
{ "cd" : { "$lte" : ISODate("2013-06-30T09:12:29Z") , "$gte" : ISODate("2013-06-11T09:12:29Z")}}
```

To use with **MongoTemplate** and **Query**.

At the moment i am doing and approach like:

```
 Query query = new Query();
 query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("cd").lte(request.getTo()).gte(request.getFrom()));
 mongoTemplate.find(query,MyDesiredEntity.class)
```

But the query above returns no results when the first one returns around 15 which it should(request.getTo and request.getFrom are **java.util.Date**).

Is there a way to achieve this with **org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got this to work by reversing the lte and gte calls.  I wrote a test to show it working:

```
@Test
public void shouldBeAbleToQueryBetweenTwoDates() throws Exception {
    // setup
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");

    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(new Mongo(), "TheDatabase");
    DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("myObject");
    // cleanup
    collection.drop();

    // date that should match
    Date expectedDate = dateFormat.parse("2013-06-12T00:00:00Z");
    collection.insert(new BasicDBObject("cd", expectedDate));
    // date that should not match (it's last year)
    collection.insert(new BasicDBObject("cd", dateFormat.parse("2012-06-12T00:00:00Z")));

    // create and execute the query
    final Date to = dateFormat.parse("2013-06-30T09:12:29Z");
    final Date from = dateFormat.parse("2013-06-11T09:12:29Z");

    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("cd").gte(from).lte(to));

    // check it returned what we expected
    List<MyObject> basicDBObjects = mongoTemplate.find(query, MyObject.class);
    Assert.assertEquals(1, basicDBObjects.size());
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedDate, basicDBObjects.get(0).cd);
}
```

Notes:

- This is TestNG not JUnit
- I'm using SimpleDateFormat just to make testing of dates easier and (maybe) more readable

The main thing to note is:

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("cd").gte(from).lte(to));
```

Before I reversed the order of the `lte` and `gte` the query was returning nothing.

Comment: Call me Ishmael. It works...i never even suspected that the when building queries with criteria the order of the clauses actually matter. Thanks a lot this was really bugging me

Comment: but is this behavior desirable? shouldn't the result be the same?

Comment: I agree, the order should not matter.  And now I'm playing with the order in my test, I can't get it to fail again...

Comment: this seems to be a bug in my opinion, each time i replaced the order of the gte and lte calls i get the same behavior

Comment: Sorry I don't understand - are you saying it fails when you have it as lte before gte, and passes when gte is before lte, or are you saying that it passes both ways?  I've tried reversing the order in the test above, and it still passes.